# CSS issues with div on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I positioned transparent div over an image to link a part of the image. This works perfectly in firefox, opera, chrome en safari. But when I tried this on IE it gave issues. Naturally I thought it was a problem of css positions, but when I gave the div a background-color, it suddenly works.

Is it possible to use a div with transparent background to link something?

HTML:

```
<div id="linksabout" class="links" ></div>
<div id="linksnames" class="links" ></div>
<div id="linksabc" class="links" ></div>
<div id="linkscontact" class="links" ></div>
<div id="linksnews" class="links" ></div>
```

Link with jquery:

```
$('#home').click(function()
{
    change_page(1);
});
$('#about').click(function()
{
    change_page(2);
});
```

and so on...

width and height is defined by css.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have come accross this issue before with IE, one solution will be to use an image map, or you could add a background colour and set the opacity to 0

`#home{
background-color:#000;
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */`}